# Laravel collection with ampersand undefined property

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I am `dd`ing a collection like so as I'm having a problem looking for a property on the object:

```
dd($this->plan);
```

Output:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#5314
  #items: array:3 [
    "ageRange" => "Under 18"
    "goal" => null
    "duration" => & "Indefinitely"
  ]
}
```

I am looking for the property `duration` on this object, but when I hit: `$plan->duration` I get the following error:

```
dd($this->plan->duration);
```

I get the following error:

```
Property [duration] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

I believe it's something to do with this `&` but I am not sure why it's there or where it's come from

Comment: First just returns the first value in the array, so that's not helpful unfortunately

Comment: SO I've updated to provide a better example of the array, if I hit `$this->plan->first()` I get the string `Under 18` out and nothing else

Comment: (Cleaned up some comments). It's definitely clearer now; can you provide the code that generates this Collection? And does the answer below work?

Comment: The collection is provided by the front end as part of the request, all I do is collect it like so: `$this->plan = collect($plan);`

Comment: Gotcha! Apologies for the confusion. So you're basically doing `collect(['ageRange' => 'Under 18', 'goal' => null, 'duration' => 'Indefinitely'])`, which results in a Collection of that single array. And array access `['duration']` instead of object access `->duration` is the way to go. If you want `$this->plan->duration` to work, simply do `$this->plan = (object)$plan`. Still not sure about the `&` though 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an array, not an object inside the Collection. Try either `$this->plan->get('duration')` or `$this->plan['duration']`

---

As the question/answer in the comment by [@Peppermintology](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281278/peppermintology) points out,  this is a because the 'duration' key was set by reference. To illustrate, here's a quick way to reproduce the behavior in the `tinker` console:

[image]

Comment: This does work, so have upvoted, still want to understand what's going on with the ampersand

Comment: @LewisSmith Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26485508/281278) help clear up the the ampersand for you.

Comment: The 'duration' was set as a by reference variable. I reproduced this in a `tinker` session.